# How to avoid asking for permissions from the system folder picker?

Tags: android

I call system folder picker for download with this intent:

```
Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE).setFlags(
            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
        ).let { Intent.createChooser(it, "") }
```

(Before calling intent I check permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
But every time i want to choose folder for download I have that permission request:
[image]

I want avoid asking for permissions.

Comment: If the os is asking, then you have a different permission, if it's android 11 read [this](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage)

Comment: `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` Remove that flag. Yoy cannot grant anything here.

Comment: `Before calling intent I check permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` Not needed as it is not needed for ACTIIN_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.

Comment: @blackapps removing the flag didn't help(

Comment: Of course not. But it should not be there was the message. And why dont you translate that message? And Litres? Whats that?